# How to find the NP decision Rule for false alarm and the power of that decision

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

Suppose we observe a random variable Y given by:
Y=N+Ө λ
where Ө is either 0 or 1, λ is a fixed number between 0 and 2, and where N is a random variable that has a uniform density (-1,1). We wish to decide between the hypothesis
H0: Ө=0
Versus H1: Ө=1
a)find the Neyman-Pearson decision rule for false alarm probability ranging from 0 to 1.
b) Find the power of the Neyman-Pearson decision rule as a functionof the false alarm probability and the parameter λ. Sketch the receiver operating characteristics.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to find the pdf for H1 and H0, for H0 Y=N, H1:Y=N+λ. I am not sure what the likelihood ratio is going to be but I think it is p1/p0 which is 1/2(1+λ) from -1 to 1 and zero otherwise I am struggling with finding the false alarm probability from this uniform distribution

Comment: Add your thoughts/attempts on the main post by editing it.

Comment: Like what StubbornAtom said, please click on the tiny `edit` and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Comment: Since $\lambda$ is positive, it seems sensible that you should be rejecting $H_0$ for observed values of $Y$ above a threshold and not rejecting $H_0$ for observed values below that threshold.  The  false alarm probability and the power will change with the threshold and this should give you a way into the questions